# timer keeps resetting in react-native

Tags: react-native, rendering, countdowntimer

I am developing a react-native quiz application. Where i will fetch 5 questions from the backend and display them one by one to user. User can skip the current question or can answer current question to go to next question.

There is a timer on the top that will start countdown from 300 seconds.

Now the problem i am facing is that whenever the user skips/attempt the question (visit next next question), timer resets itself and start countdown again from 300 seconds.

I want to keep the timer running even after next question is visited.
Can anyone please help me resolving this?

if anyone need i can give example code what/how i am implementing this.

Below is example code :

```
export default class QuestionLayout extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentQuestion: 0,
        questionsData: {}
    };
}

handleSkipQuestion() {
    this.props.next_question();
}


render() {
    const data = this.props.questions;

        return (
            <View>
               <Col>
                 <CountdownCircle seconds={60} radius={25} />
               </Col>           
               <Button rounded onPress={this.handleSkipQuestion}    //for going to next question
                />
                <View >
                   <Card>
                     <CardItem>
                        <MyWebView
                            style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                 marginRight: 20
                                }}
                                source={{
                                    html: this.wrapMathjax(questionData) //for displaying questoins
                                }}
                            />
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in the next function? is it re-rendering the quiz component? can you share the component tree

Comment: please add [mcve]

Comment: yes, i am calling the nextQuestion action creator which is re-rendering the questionLayout and returning the new value new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this.

```
<QuizComponent>
   <Timer />
   <QuestionWithOptions />
   <ActionButtons />
</QuizComponent
```

1.`QuizComponent` will be the top level component which will fetch the data for the
quiz.and it will keep the state of the entire quiz.

2.`Timer` will take timer details from `QuizComponent` and its task is to run
the timer and notify the parent when time is over.

3.`QestionWithOptions` will take the question data from the parent and render it 
in a way you want it. user can select the correct anwser from the options and notify the change to the parent so that parent keeps track of what has changed with what values,

4.`ActionButtons` will have buttons that will change the questions or submit the quiz by notifiying the parent.

all the data and state will be maintained by the `QuizComponent`, when user hits next question the data for`QuestionWithOptions` will only change.
thus your Quiz state is preserved. your timer is happy

Answer (score 0):

You should start your timer in constructor or componentDidMount. Thus if page rerender your timer wont reset